# VHDL. Performance of comparator

Tags: performance, vhdl, modelsim

I am creating small chip block on vhdl - comparator.
Use: QuartusII, ModelSim, simulate on Cyclone ii.

```
INPUT:  
    IN_FIRST: in UNSIGNED(255 downto 0);  
    IN_SECOND: in UNSIGNED(255 downto 0);  

OUTPUT:  
    OUT_IS_RIGHT_RESULT: out STD_LOGIC; -- IN_SECOND < IN_FIRST
```

I have some different parallel and sequential realizations. But parallel works worse in some cases than sequential. 
And I can't find best approach.

**Some different realizations:**

*With generate (time-18.5ns)*

```
architecture ComparatorArch of Comparator is
    signal T: UNSIGNED(7 downto 0) := (others => 'U');
    signal H: UNSIGNED(7 downto 0) := (others => 'U');
begin
    generateG: for i in 7 downto 0 generate
        T(i) <= '1' when (IN_FIRST((i + 1) * 32 - 1 downto i * 32) > IN_SECOND((i + 1) * 32 - 1 downto i * 32)) else '0';
        H(i) <= '1' when (IN_FIRST((i + 1) * 32 - 1 downto i * 32) < IN_SECOND((i + 1) * 32 - 1 downto i * 32)) else '0';
    end generate generateG;

    OUT_TARG <= T;
    OUT_HASH <= H;
    OUT_IS_RIGHT_RESULT <= (T(7) or ((not T(7)) and ((not H(7)) and 
        (T(6) or ((not T(6)) and ((not H(6)) and 
        (T(5) or ((not T(5)) and ((not H(5)) and 
        (T(4) or ((not T(4)) and ((not H(4)) and 
        (T(3) or ((not T(3)) and ((not H(3)) and 
        (T(2) or ((not T(2)) and ((not H(2)) and 
        (T(1) or ((not T(1)) and ((not H(1)) and T(0))))))))))))))))))))));
end ComparatorArch;
```

Last part - it's logical representation of comparing `T` and `H`.

*In process (time-35ns)*

```
architecture ComparatorArch of Comparator is
begin
  mainP: process(IN_READY) begin
        if (rising_edge(IN_READY) and IN_READY = '1') then
            if (IN_SECOND < IN_FIRST) then
                OUT_IS_RIGHT_RESULT <= '1';
            else
                OUT_IS_RIGHT_RESULT <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
  end process;
end ComparatorArch;
```

May be somebody knows better approach.

And it doesn't work if i change

```
if (rising_edge(IN_READY) and IN_READY = '1') then
```

to

```
if (IN_READY = '1') then
```

Why?

I investigated some basic things on examples and realized that chip has logical and calculation blocks of special input data size.
It compares or calculate logical operations const time for signals that has size from min to specific max value.
It compares BIT/BIT or BIT_VECTOR(7 down to 0)/BIT_VECTOR(7 down to 0) for the same time - about 9ns. Why so long time? Can somebody explain it?

Comment: I only vaguely understand your notation, but I used to design ICs.  When building an equal/not-equal comparator you need to compare bit to bit, then combine pairs of results, then combine pairs of pairs, etc.  This way the gate delay is proportional to log N.  If you "daisy-chain" the results of the individual bit compares, on the other hand, you get a delay proportional to N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As earlier commented, a parallel tree will have the best performance as you widen the comparator. For a comparator as narrow as 8 bits, however, routing delays can dominate and the Cyclone II will perform better using its carry chains (see section 2-2 of the [Cyclone II device handbook](http://www.altera.com/literature/lit-cyc2.jsp)) since they connect directly to neighboring LEs. This is why serial logic can outperform parallel.

As for rising_edge, you've written a mix of two conventions. Before rising_edge was standard, the same function was performed using `clk'event and event='1'`; since rising_edge already defines the new state as '1' there's no need to test it. Testing for a high level *alone*, on the other hand, produces not a [D flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#D_flip-flop) but a [transparent latch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#Gated_D_latch) - a rarely desired function most FPGAs are not optimized for, and the synthesis tools tend to warn about this.

As for your timing results, without seeing the test method I can't read anything from the time you mention. Is it even about a post-fitting simulation? It's rare that it's worth going to that extent for such a small function.

Comment: I am simulating in ModelSim, in options I set: cycloneii library, .sdo file (that Quartus generate) and current .vhd file. I don't have test files, I use "force" signal directly.

Comment: Open up the static timing analyzer report, or timequest itself. You can get step by step reports of every signal delay there; for instance, if this 512 to 9 bit function is implemented with I/Os, the delays of transporting the values from such a large spread of I/Os will be notable. A closely related detail is that without an SDC telling it the limits, the fitter may essentially abandon performance for external asynchronous signals.